# Docker cannot access .local domains

Tags: docker

I am trying to access devices on my network with .local domain, but it doesn't seem to work in Docker.

Ping from host is working:

```
$ ping test1.local
PING test1.local (192.168.1.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.90 (192.168.1.90): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.41 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.90 (192.168.1.90): icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.54 ms
```

Docker demon config:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
    "dns": ["192.168.1.1","8.8.8.8"]
}
```

If I try to ping test1.local from Docker:

```
$ sudo docker run --network host busybox ping -c 3 test1.local
ping: bad address 'test1.local'
```

Pinging device with IP works:

```
$ sudo docker run --network host busybox ping -c 3 192.168.1.90
PING 192.168.1.90 (192.168.1.90): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.90: seq=0 ttl=255 time=4.855 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.90: seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.566 ms
```

So I assume something is wrong name resolution.

```
madrian@ubuntudev:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search localdomain
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where is the DNS server running that defines these host names?

Comment: It's on my router 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score -1):

Try run your code **without** `--network host` argument. The problem is in the DNS resolution.

When you use `default bridge` (which will be used if you omit `network` parameter), containers inherit DNS configuration from host, and that is what you need:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

When you use `user-defined bridge`, Docker updates DNS records to enable seamless communication between containers by their names:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

Unfortunately, I was unable to find explicit explanation on how DNS works with `host` mode, so I assume this is a problem

Comment: Unfortunately not working, I already tried with and without `--network host`. In meantime I opened an issue on GitHub, maybe this problem is related to an other issue? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38531